how backup and restore in Visual Studio 2019
I am looking for a way to restore my past data and settings. But I can't find a suitable way. If possible, suggest a principled and professional way, if possible, with a video link. Thank you in advance for your kindness.

Do you mean your user settings and preferences in Visual Studio, or do you mean backup of your projects? A great way to back up your projects is to use git-hub, and that will allow you with ease to have a copy of any of your projects available with great ease when you start working on a different computer, or in fact have several computers you use to work on such projects.  You can associate a logon with visual studio, and thus your user preferences and settings will travel to each computer you use. So, it not clear what you mean by "past data"? Is past data your projects?

For backup your projects you can use version control system with git to store your code in public platforms based on your preference.
If you want to store your settings, you can launch Visual Studio Installer and select "Export Configuration" under the VS instance that you have installed so you can use on other VS instances during installation.
